# What the difference between “doorman” and “porter”

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, difference

I was searching for hotel vocabulary, because I’m finishing my tourism course and I saw these two words. I thought  they were both the same meaning. Basically I understand for “doorman” and “porter”, the man who is in the front of the hotel and who can helps with the luggage. 
I saw these two words like different types of hotel work. Isn’t it?

Answer (score 2):

It could be two jobs.

The doorman stands at the door and welcomes guests. Typically he would stay at the door all day. Typically this would be an older gentleman.

The porter works inside the hotel, carrying bags. Typically this would be a young man.

Most hotels don't have traditional "doormen" anymore, but may have "security" at the door. You might see doormen at very traditional and expensive hotels.

Answer (score 1):

**Basically I understand for “doorman” and “porter”, the man who is in the front of the hotel and who can helps with the luggage.**

Although Nothing James has said is incorrect I think there is a need to expand his answer.

By definition **A Porter can be a Doorman but a Doorman is not a Porter.** Therefore you thoughts that they are the same is not far from the truth, but not exactly correct either.

> **porter: noun (PERSON)​** [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/porter)
>
> **a person whose job is to carry things**, especially travellers' bags at railway stations, airports, **hotels etc**.:
>
> (UK)**someone whose job** is to take care of a large building where many people live and **be present at its entrance** in order to help people who live or visit there: ​**(US would use doorman)**
>
> (US) a person whose job is to help travellers who are spending the night on a train by arranging their bed, taking care of their bags, etc.
>
> **doorman**: [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/doorman?q=Doorman) noun: a person whose job is to stand by the door of a hotel or public building and allow people to go in or out, and to open their car doors, etc.